# consecutive use of \cite references

Tags: multiple-citations

I have some text with a lot of instances where \cite{} was used consecutively.

This:

```
\cite{Burgmer:2009aa}\cite{Robinson:2011bi}\cite{Kuchinad:2007ff}\cite{Lutz:2008ew})
```

Becomes:

```
[1][2][3][4]
```

How can I have them show up as a singe reference range rather than several consecutive references?

Desired output:

```
[1-4]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Do you use natbib and BibTeX? Please add a minimal compilable example.

Answer (score 3):

Along with placing all citation keys in the argument of a single `\cite` command, you need to load a suitable citation management package. I suggest you load either the `cite` package or the `natbib` package with options `numbers` and `sort&compress`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a, author = "A", title  = "uuu", year   = 3001, }
@misc{b, author = "B", title  = "vvv", year   = 3002, }
@misc{c, author = "C", title  = "www", year   = 3003, }
@misc{d, author = "D", title  = "xxx", year   = 3004, }
\end{filecontents}

% bibliography style that can generate numeric-style citation callouts:
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
% or: \usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b,c,d}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\cite{Burgmer:2009aa,Robinson:2011bi,Kuchinad:2007ff,Lutz:2008ew}
```

This gives [1-4] in several systems, but I gather it depends upon which style you're using.

Comment: Assuming the document doesn't load a suitable citation management package, your setup generates `[1,2,3,4,]`, *not* `[1-4]`.